# Multiple toggles better structured

Tags: jquery

I have multiple markup-blocks which' display get toggled by something like

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".target").toggle(showOrHide);
});
```

Those blocks are rarely identic by tag, id or parent/child-structure in general. As thereby I am having quite some crowded place with all those blocks to be displayed/not and triggers, I was wondering, if that isn't simplifyable. Therefore I'd like to do something like that:

Make the target of a trigger identifiablye by adding a special string to the classname of it, like:

```
$(".foo").click(function() {
    $(".foo_target").toggle(showOrHide);
});
```

Is therefore a chance to get the classname of the trigger > Save it in a variable > add the string (in this example "_target") to the existing triggername and toggle that class-name?

Would something like that make sense, or are there more elegant - doable ones for a non-coder like me - ways to do it?

```
$("this").click(function() {
    var targetname = $(this).attr("class");
    if ($("targetname:contains('trigger')")) {
        var targetname = targetname."_target";
    }
});
```

And if that'd make sense, how would I append the var targetname to the URL (in that scenario shown above as a URL-param like "?q=targetname"?

Thanks a lot!

Here is a scenario, that one could put in scheme, but that's not really what I am after:

```
 <section id="autoren-teaser">
        <div>
            <h3 class="trigger">Cat</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3 class="trigger">Bird</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3 class="trigger">Dog</h3>
        </div>
    </section>
        <div class="target">
                <img src="cat.gif" />
                <h2>Content_foo</h2>
                <p>Foo</p><a class="knopf trigger_zu">Schliessen</a>
        </div>
 <div class="target">
                <img src="dog.gif" />
                <h2>Content_foo</h2>
                <p>Foo</p><a class="knopf trigger_zu">Schliessen</a>
        </div>
 <div class="target">
                <img src="bird.gif" />
                <h2>Content_foo</h2>
                <p>Foo</p><a class="knopf trigger_zu">Schliessen</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is the HTML the same in all instances? Could you post an example of it if so.

Comment: You don't need to create unique identity for all the elements. Share your html.

Comment: It's not that much about a solution for a single problem, but rather thought in general: Commonly I have like 3-6 blocks in a project that must get toggled. And there is no real scheme to them. It could be the trigger sits in footer and the target is a section within an article. But of course it could also be a parent-element, that needs to toggle child. Though I added something, but as said - it's not so much about making that work, but rather to have sort of a global routine for toggling elements.

Comment: knopf = button, Schliessen = close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is acceptable to alter all html parts, you could assign multiple classes to both trigger and target, so that only the targets with corresponding classes (except'trigger') are affected.

e.g.
trigger:

```
<h3 class="trigger cat">Cat</h3>
```

target:

```
 <div class="target cat">
```

toggle:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    var targettype = $(this).attr('class').replace('trigger','').trim();
    if(targettype)            
       $('.target.' + targettype).toggle();
});
```

Live example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ex958fpz/)

The *replace* simply removes `trigger` from the class attribute `trigger cat` (and trims to remove the leading/trailing spaces). The `'.target.' + targettype` creates the jquery class criterium to match all targets with the specified class type. If you want to use more than one class, some additional class parsing is needed, but that shouldn't be too much work.

About using an url parameter: by using the combined class construction, you can always get any target object(s) you want with the jquery `.target.classtype` construction, where classtype is determined by your (url) parameter

Answer (score 0):

With this scipt

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                // make the toggle buttons work
                $(".trigger").click(function(event) {
                    $($(event.target).attr('class').replace("trigger ",".target."))
                        .toggle("hidden");
                });

                // make the close buttons work
                $(".trigger_zu").click(function(event) {
                    $(event.target).parent().toggle("hidden");
                });
            });
```

I could make this work

```
        <section id="autoren-teaser">
            <div>
                <h3 class="trigger cat">toggle Cat</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 class="trigger bird">toggle Bird</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3 class="trigger dog">toggle Dog</h3>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="target cat">
                <h2>Content_Cat</h2>
                <img src="cat.gif" />
                <a class="knopf trigger_zu">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div class="target bird">
                <h2>Content_Dog</h2>
                <img src="dog.gif" />
                <a class="knopf trigger_zu">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div class="target">
                <h2>Content_Bird</h2>
                <img src="bird.gif dog" />
                <a class="knopf trigger_zu">Close</a>
        </div>
```